# Thumbnail image from Google Place Picker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

How to get a thumbnail image of a map centered on a given location from Android Google map and place picker api?

I know about google static map api. However, since place picker is already showing the map, it already has the bitmap and hence it should be instantaneous to access instead of downloading from the static map api.

Any idea? Thanks for any insight.